# Checkbox save onchange function

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, onchange

I'm trying to create a script that will save a ticked checkbox. The code I have as of now disables add & approve when read is ticked and disables read when either of add/approve is ticked. Now the problem I have is when I added ajax submission to the jquery it doesn't save the record and it no longer disables the checkboxes(assuming I ticked read).

Here's what I got so far.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#list-tbl tr').each(function(){

        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $('#input').val();
        $('input[type=checkbox]', $this).change(function(){
            if($('.read', $this).is(':checked')){
                $('input[type=checkbox]', $this).prop('disabled',true);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: <?= site_url('admin/update')?>,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { id: id }, 
                    success: function(data) { 
                        alert("Updated");
            }
        });
                $(this).prop('disabled',false);
            } else if($('.add', $this).is(':checked') || $('.approve', $this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.read', $this).prop('disabled', true);
                $(this).prop('disabled', false);
            } else{
                $('input[type=checkbox]', $this).prop('disabled',false);
                $(this).prop('disabled',false);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/bGatX/

I'm getting a lil bit frustrated I just want to save the data in the right manner and perform the disabling as it is....

Many thanks.

Comment: From our perspective, it's sort of difficult to identify what your issue actually is. Would you consider making a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the accompanying HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your jsFiddle... you don't actually have a HTML element with `id="input"`, even though, you've trying to save an id using: `var id = $('#input').val();`

This is the id you're trying to send to the server but it doesn't really exist. What are you really trying to do? Establish whether a certain user has read/added/approved a particular item? If that's the case what you need to send to the server is a user id combined with a string that represents whether the user read/added or approved an item.

On a minor note and as a matter of redundancy and performance: `$(this).prop('disabled',false);` is common amongst all conditionals and can be pulled out to the front as a common factor.